# What does strncmp actually do?

Tags: c

I tried to create my own strncmp function that was required from my school project, I run my code that use the same srcmp function but  with providing the limit size for which ASCII Code I want to compare:
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int     strncmp(char *s1, char *s2, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    int diff;

    i = 0;
    diff = 0;
    while ((s1[i] != '\0' || s2[i] != '\0') && (unsigned)i < n)
    {
        diff = s1[i] - s2[i];
        if (diff != 0)
        {
            break ;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (diff);
}
int main(){
    char s11[] = "abcs";
    char s12[] = "zzfs";
    unsigned int p = 3;
    printf("%d", strncmp(s11, s12, p));
}
```

The output :

```
-22
```

It's supposed to compare the 3 characters not only the first one, Am I right ?
I didn't get the idea in MAN, I'm a beginner just so you know.
Thanks  for your help!

Comment: Should it not be checking that both `s1[I]` _and_ `s2[I]` are not equal to `'\0'`?

Comment: The way you have it, it will exit the function when the first non matching character is found.

Comment: Also `-22` doesn't make sense, it should return `-25`.

Comment: I didn't get it ?

Comment: @alex01011 So the size does not compare if they didn't match ? But in strcmt it compare the characters and return a int, Positive, negative or equal.

Comment: It should return `'a' - 'z'`, which values are `97 - 122`, therefore `-25`.

Comment: @ChrisDutton: That part seems okay.  If one of them is zero and the other isn't, we enter the loop body, which will set `diff` to nonzero and break out of the loop.  We don't run off the end of the string.

Comment: I would recommend to use the `size_t` type for the `n` argument and for the `i` iterator.

Comment: @ChrisDutton no, it absolutely should not.

Answer (score 2):

> What does strncmp actually do?

`strncmp` compares the first two characters in the strings. (When comparing characters, it uses their values as `unsigned char`, even though they are passed via pointers to `char`.) If the characters differ or either is a null character:

- If the character from the first string is greater than the character from the second, `strncmp` returns a positive value.
- If the first is less than the second, `strncmp` returns a negative value.
- Otherwise (the characters are both null characters), `strncmp` returns zero.

If the characters did not differ and neither was a null character, `strncmp` goes on to compare the following characters in the same way, until `n` pairs have been compared. If no difference has been found after `n` pairs have been compared, `strncmp` returns zero.

Some implementations of `strncmp` may return the signed difference between the two characters that differed, but this is not required by the C standard. `strncmp` may simply return +1 and −1 for “greater than” and “less than” or may use other positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1):

`strncmp(s1, s2, n)` compares up to `n` characters from the strings pointed to by `s1` and `s2`. It stops if it finds a difference and returns a negative value if the character from `s1`, converted to an `unsigned char` is less than the corresponding character from `s2` (also converted to an `unsigned char`) and a positive value it is is greater. Subtracting the values of the differing characters is a handy way to compute a return value with the correct sign.

If no difference was found before the end of both strings or `n` characters have been processed, whichever comes first, it returns `0`.

Your code has some small issues:

- the pointer arguments should be declared with type `const char *` and `n` with type `size_t`.
- similarly, `i` should be defined as a `size_t`, defining it as an `int` forces you to use a cast in the comparison and will cause undefined behavior for strings with an identical prefix longer than `INT_MAX` and a large enough `n` argument.
- you should not dereference `s1[i]` nor `s2[i]` if `n` has reached `0`, so the test on `n` should be performed first.
- the difference should be computed as `diff = (unsigned char)s1[i] - (unsigned char)s2[i];`
- note also that on some very exotic platforms, where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, the subtraction cannot be used as it may wrap around and produce incorrect results.
- it is preferable to not use names reserved for standard functions for your own versions and it may cause clashes with the compiler's intrinsics.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int diff = (unsigned char)s1[i] - (unsigned char)s2[i];
        if (diff != 0 || s1[i] == '\0')
            return diff;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char s11[] = "abcs";
    char s12[] = "zzfs";
    size_t n = 3;
    printf("   strncmp() -> %d\n", strncmp(s11, s12, n));
    printf("my_strncmp() -> %d\n", my_strncmp(s11, s12, n));
    return 0;
}
```

The output values may differ but should have the same sign or should both be null.

Comment: Why didn't you check to see if the second string's current character is NULL ('\0') in your `if (diff != 0 || s1[i] == '\0')`? Is there some assumption with the input strings that idk about?

Comment: @Stev: there is no assumption, just deduction: if the byte values differ, the difference is `!= 0` and returned, other wise they are equal and if `s[i]` is a null terminator, `s2[i]` is also a null terminator (remember that the difference is 0) and the strings compare equal, returning `diff` works to return `0` as `diff == 0`. An alternative implementation with similar performance would replace the test with `if (diff != 0) return diff; if (s1[i] == '\0') break;`